# How to access single XML value from URL using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, parsing, url

I am extremely new to Node.js and programming in general. My question is that i'm trying to access one or more values from from a URL's XML, rather then the every value from the URL's XML.

Instead of just using this code below and receiving every value:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

[Retrieving every value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKjjl.png)

I have tried using this line of code instead:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, ['Destination', 'Origintime']));
```

but it comes up empty.

Here is the code i'm working with.

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var http = require('http');
var url = "http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByNameXML?StationDesc=Malahide"

var info = '';

function xmlToJson(url, callback) {
  var req = http.get(url, function(res) {
    var xml = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      xml += chunk;
    });

    res.on('error', function(e) {
      callback(e, null);
    }); 

    res.on('timeout', function(e) {
      callback(e, null);
    }); 

    res.on('end', function() {
      parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
        callback(null, result);
      });
    });
  });
}

xmlToJson(url, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        // Handle this however you like
        return console.err(err);
        res.send('Error')
    }

    //This way below works, however pulls in every value from xml url.
    info = '' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + ''
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

    //This way provides no values from url xml.
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, ['Direction', 'Destination', 'Exparrival']));
    //info = '' + JSON.stringify(data, ['Direction', 'Destination', 'Exparrival']) + ''
});
```

Hopefully you guys can help, thanks!

Comment: I had been following this tutorial: http://antrikshy.com/blog/fetch-xml-url-convert-to-json-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
JSON.stringify(data.map(function (i) {
    return {
        'Direction' : i['Direction'],
        'Destination' : i['Destination'],
        'Exparrival' : i['Exparrival']
    }
}))
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(data.map(function (i) {
 return {
  'Direction' : i['Direction'],
  'Destination' : i['Destination'],
  'Exparrival' : i['Exparrival']
 }
}))